# I am having trouble applying a javascript file to Wordpress. How Do I Enqueue Scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, themes

I am having trouble applying javascript with a dependency of jQuery on my wordpress site, The css function worked but not the javascript function. Any tips or help?

http://minecraftserverzz.com/youtube/

```
function wp_chiquedesigns_styles() {

   wp_enqueue_style( 'style_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_chiquedesigns_styles' );

function chiquedesigns_child_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'main js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), true);

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_chiquedesigns_child_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'main js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), true);
```

The above code is producing the following path:

http://minecraftserverzz.com/youtube/wp-content/themes/Chique%20Designs.zip/js/main.js

Which is a 404 - file does not exist.

get_stylesheet_directory_uri() returns the following string.

```
http://minecraftserverzz.com/youtube/wp-content/themes/Chique%20Designs.zip/js
```

It looks like your main.js file is in the folder level above that. Try moving your main.js file into the js folder

Comment: Ok, the directory is right now but, the jQuery script isn't working like its supposed to? I know this may be a waste of you time, but can you please check my script? http://minecraftserverzz.com/youtube/wp-content/themes/Chique%20Designs.zip/js/main.js

Comment: @McDiamund If you open up the console on the page you'll see that there's some errors. The first one being a syntax error on line 40 in your main.js file.

Comment: Thank You so much, I fixed all the issues and now i'm back on track :) When in need, other people can help.

Comment: @McDiamund No problem, I am happy you were able to fix your resolve your main.js issues.